# How to make Vim not fold everything automatically?

Tags: vim, code-folding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [vim: enable folds but don't automatically close them](https://superuser.com/questions/169973/vim-enable-folds-but-dont-automatically-close-them)

Whenever I open Vim, it automatically folds everything. So the first thing I invariably do is to unfold everything.

Is there a way to automate this?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

To unfold all folds, use the keys

```
zR
```

In order to adjust the initial fold level, play around with the `foldlevel`, e.g.

```
:set foldlevel=1
```

will open all the  *highest level* folds, a very high number will thus open all folds. Find out which level `1, 2, 3, ...` is the one you want.

To make this static, edit your `~/.vimrc` and add:

```
set foldlevelstart=1
```

duplicate of this [question](https://superuser.com/q/169973/16658).

Comment: In case someone is wondering how to fold all folds: `zM`

Comment: What does zM stands for?

Comment: To disable folding entirely, use `set nofoldenable`.

Comment: @luis.espinal `zR` probably stands for *reduce* folding while `zM` stands for *more* folding.

Comment: @luis.espinal and `z` looks like a folded piece of paper